# Connecting to a different MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, connection

I've purchased a server and I have a database on there. But whenever I enter MySQL Command Line Client it just says "Password:" and then i can only put in the password for the database on my computer. Is there a way I can make it so I can connect to my other database? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As documented under [mysql Options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-command-options.html):

> mysql supports the following options, which can be specified on the command line or in the `[mysql]` and `[client]` groups of an option file.
>
> ```
> +------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------+
> |      Format      | Option File |                   Description                 |
> +------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------+
> :                  :             :                                               :
> | --host=host_name | host        | Connect to the MySQL server on the given host |
> :                  :             :                                               :
> +------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------+
> ```